# C++ overload << (invalid use of non static member)

Tags: c++, overloading

The problem is that I want output of my program using

```
Ackermann<M,N>::wartosc;
```

i wanted to do it by overload operator <<, but when just in main i can type

```
cout << Ackermann<M,N>::wartosc;
```

there is a problem too.

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int M, int N>
class Ackermann {
    private:
        int n0, m0; 

        int count(int m, int n)
        {
            if ( m == 0 ) return n+1;
            else if ( m > 0 && n == 0 ){ return count(m-1,1);}
            else if ( m > 0 && n > 0 ) { return count(m-1,count(m,n-1));}   
            return -1;      
        }   
    public:

        Ackermann()
        {
            n0 = N;
            m0 = M;
        }

        int wartosc()
        {
            return count(m0,n0);
        }               

        template<int M1, int N1>
        friend ostream & operator<< (ostream &wyjscie, const Ackermann<M1,N1> &s); 
};


template<int M, int N>
ostream & operator<< (ostream &output, const Ackermann<M,N> &s)         
 {
    return output << Ackermann<M,N>::wartosc;
 }


int main()
{
    Ackermann<3, 3> function;

    cout << function << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the error is

```
ack.cpp:38:36: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int Ackermann<M, N>::wartosc() [with int M = 3, int N = 3]’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *call* the member function on instance `s`:

```
return output << s.wartosc();
//                        ^^
```

Next, since you are passing a `const` reference, you need to make the `count` and `wartosc` methods `const`:

```
int count(int m, int n) const { .... 

int wartosc() const { ...
```

Comment: >return output << s.wartosc();

still gives an error

>ack.cpp:38:29: error: passing ‘const Ackermann<3, 3>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Ackermann<M, N>::wartosc() [with int M = 3, int N = 3]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

but is there a way to use  

>Ackermann<M,N>::wartosc

?

Comment: it works when i use *const*. But is it a way to use     Ackermann<M,N>::wartosc ?

Comment: @user3009072 there are ways, but it is complicated. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: For learn and for school. My teacher want it by using as i said. If you cant explain it by now just say it, cause you already solved my problem but using other way.

Comment: @user3009072 something like this: `s.Ackermann<M,N>::wartosc()`. Basically, you gain nothing from it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is here: `Ackermann<M,N>::wartosc`
You are treating it like a static method. Instead change it to use the `s` parameter passed in.

```
template<int M, int N>
ostream & operator<< (ostream &output, const Ackermann<M,N> &s)         
{
    return output << s.wartosc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the member function AND preferably on the instance...

```
return output << s.wartosc();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found clang++ error message more understandable:

```
ack.cpp:37:38: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
    return output << Ackermann<M,N>::wartosc;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

You are calling the wartosc like it was a static function but it's not. Replace it by:

```
return output << s.wartosc;
```